# Angular JS Redirecting to another page with parameter

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, redirect

How can i redirect this to another page like welcome.html with parameter. i am stuff with this, i am using url and for redirect to another page from submitForm() function in `angularjs`, but not redirecting to welcome page, even not showing any parameter and post method(*inspect element > network > reload*) on click.

> please someone suggest that how can i redirect to another page in `angularjs` because of i think here `URL:` is not redirecting.

as well as suggestion code to show textbox value (parameters) on another page on buttom click.

[code in plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qslUdglFfJcxPIYF4PK2?p=preview)

```
    <body ng-app="postApp" ng-controller="postController">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1>Post data</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- FORM -->
                <form name="userForm"  ng-submit="submitForm()">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Uer ID</label>
                        <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" ng-model="user.id">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Customer Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cust" class="form-control" ng-model="user.cust">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Customer ID</label>
                        <input type="text" name="c_id" class="form-control" ng-model="user.c_id">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter your mobile no.</label>
                        <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control" ng-model="user.mobile">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
                        <script>
                            var postApp = angular.module('postApp', []);
                            postApp.controller('postController', function ($scope, $http) {
                                $scope.user = {};
                                $scope.submitForm = function () {
                                    $http({
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        url: 'welcome.html',
                                        templateUrl: clone.html',
                                        data: $scope.user,
                                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                                    })
                                  .success(function (data) {
                                      alert("form posted");
                                  });
                                };
                            });
                        </script>
```

Comment: So you want to go to the `welcome.html` and take the `$scope.user` data with you?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to another page from your function and share data with the new page, use the **$location** service with the search function, something like this:

```
$location.path('/home').search('id=' + $scope.user.id ...);
```

If you have too much parameter to share, you can do that with a service:

```
postApp.service('userData', function() {
    this.user = {};

    this.setUser = function(data) {
        this.user = data;
    };

    this.getUser = function() {
        return this.user;
    }
})
```

Then call setUser in the first page ($scope.submitForm function) and getUser in the second page.

Comment: inside your **$scope.submitForm** function

Comment: instead of **$http({...})**, and don't forget to inject the $location service

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to redirect using `$http` service(at least not what you're trying to achieve) or only using `$location`. You will have to use `$route` service.

[Angular Route Documnentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)